asp.net textbox clientside lost focus event in listview control
I have below lines of code in asp:list view control, if user input any value on 2nd text box, on client side lost focus event I need to calculate txtTokensReq * txtQty and display in lblTotalTokens.
 <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstView" ClientIDMode="Static" GroupItemCount="1" OnItemDataBound="lstView_ItemDataBound">

<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="inputQty" MaxLength="5" ID="txtTokensReq" ClientIDMode="Static" Text='<%# Eval("PartToken")%>' ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox runat="server" cssClass="inputQty" MaxLength="5" ID="txtQty" Text='<%# Eval("Qty")%>' onKeypress ="if(!validatenumeric(this,5)){return false;}"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label ID="lblTotalTokens" CssClass="note-maxqty col-last" Text='<%# Eval("TotalTokenReq")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

 </asp:ListView>

WHen I wrote onblur function on 2nd textbox, it is firing more than once.
Thanks in advance.

can you please share your code with problem code.

This is my JS code, which is firing multiple times (basically if there are 5 rows then its firing 5 times)
function calcTokensRequired(control) {
    alert(control.value);
    return false;
}

<asp:TextBox runat="server" cssClass="inputQty" MaxLength="5" ID="txtQty" Text='<%# Eval("Qty")%>' onblur="calcTokensRequired(this);" onKeypress ="if(!validatenumeric(this,5)){return false;}"></asp:TextBox>

Ok, a few things.
Inside of a list view, it does not make sense to set client id mode = "static", since the controls will be repeated over and over. Thus, if you use static for the id, then we wind up breaking the rules of HTML and multiple controls with the same id is not allowed.
Controls in a ListView will be auto generated for each row, and they will look like this:
ListView1_Qty_0
ListView1_Qty_1
ListView1_Qty_2
. etc. for each new row

And of course, if we want to use a selector for other controls on that ONE row of data, then once again, we will need to select each control based on above ("ListView Name" + "" + Control Name + "" + Row number.
The above can be difficult, so I tend to create a JavaScript function, and we simple pass what the "base" control id was in the first place.
And it not clear why you using onkey down, you should use onchange event, since that only triggers after the user tabs out of the control (or it loses focus).
So, with this markup:
        <div style="width: 50%" id="myGridList">
            <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirst" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' Width="70px" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' Width="70px" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' Width="70px" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' Width="100px" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                                TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="52" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNights" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nights") %>' Width="35px"
                                onchange="jcalc(this,'txtNights')" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPerNight" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NightRate", "{0:C0}") %>' Width="40px" 
                                onchange="jcalc(this,'txtPerNight')" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right">
                            <asp:Label ID="txtPrice" runat="server"
                                Text='<%# Eval("Price", "{0:C2}") %>' />
                        </td>

                        <td style="text-align: center">
                            <button id="cmdDelete" runat="server" class="btn"
                                onserverclick="cmdDelete_ServerClick" tabindex="-1"
                                onclick="if (!confirm('Really delete')) {return false}">
                                <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server"
                        class="table  table-hover table-bordered table-striped borderhide">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr runat="server" style="">
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 60px">First</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 60px">Last</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 60px">City</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 70px">Hotel Name</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 140px">Description</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 60px">Nights</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 60px">Per<br />
                                    Night</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 60px">Amount</th>
                                <th runat="server" style="width: 60px"></th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <%-- skip 6 boxes --%>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                                <td style="text-align: right">Total</td>
                                <td style="text-align: right">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblTotalSum" runat="server" Width="62px" ClientIDMode="Static">
                                    </asp:Label>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>

        </div>

        <button id="cmdSave" runat="server" class="btn"
            onserverclick="cmdSave_Click" tabindex="-1">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-share">Save&ensp;/&ensp;Update</span>
        </button>

        <button id="cmdAddNew3" runat="server" class="btn" style="margin-left: 20px"
            onserverclick="cmdAddNew_Click" tabindex="-1">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign">New&ensp;Hotel</span>
        </button>

        <button id="cmdUnDo" runat="server" class="btn" style="margin-left: 20px"
            onserverclick="cmdUnDo_ServerClick" tabindex="-1">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-retweet">Undo</span>
        </button>

    </div>

    <script>
        function jcalc(ctl, tid) {

           // simple grid update price from nights X rate
            var Nights = $('#' + ctl.id.replace(tid, 'txtNights'))
            var Price = $('#' + ctl.id.replace(tid, 'txtPerNight'))
            var tAmount = $('#' + ctl.id.replace(tid, 'txtPrice'))

            var MyPrice = Nights.val() * DollarToNum(Price.val())
            tAmount.text(NumToDollar(MyPrice))

            // change save button to blue - shows edits were done
            $('#cmdSave').addClass('btn btn-info')

            // total up colum for display

            var myGrid = $("#myGridList")                   // select list view area (div)
            myTotalcols = myGrid.find("[id *= txtPrice]")   // select txtPrice from list view
            var myTotal = 0;
            myTotalcols.each(function () {
                myvalue = DollarToNum(this.innerText)
                myTotal += myvalue});

            $('#lblTotalSum').text(NumToDollar(myTotal))    // control in footer
        }


        function DollarToNum(sValue) {
            // take sring currency such as $12,555,00 and conver to number
            return Number(sValue.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, ""))
        }

        function NumToDollar(sValue) {
            // take number and convert to string with currency format
            var dollarUSLocale = Intl.NumberFormat('en-US',
                { style: "currency", currency: "USD", useGrouping: true, minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
            var resultamount = 0
            return dollarUSLocale.format(sValue)
        }
    </script>

Note how I wrapped the ListView in a div with an id, so I select that out of the page. (after all, you might have more then one ListView on the page).
And note how I simply pass the "base" control id with the JavaScript function. Since there is that "row" naming process for each row, then I just replace the text of the values I want based on the current control's id (which will include that row number and control name).
I also show how I can select each row using a wild card jQuery selector, and I used that to total up the resulting values, and place that into a footer control.
So, the result looks like this:

So, I suggest removing the ClientIDMode for controls in the ListView, since they are going to repeat, and you lose practical means to select controls from a given row.

Thanks for your reply, I don't think I can remove ClientIDMode on the listivew as I have save functionality already implemented as below.

I cannot remove ClientIDMode as I have save functionality implemented as below
function buttonLstSaveHandler() {
    var allItems = $(".qtyBox"); // <div class="qtyBox"> above listview control
    for (var i = 0; i < allItems.length; i++) 
 //logic        
    }
    if (valid && arCartItems.length > 0) {
        var params = {
            partCategoryID: partCategoryID,
            lstCartItem: arCartItems
        };
        callWebService('SaveCartItems', params, false, true, ajaxFailureHandlerCartSave, function (data) {    
        });
    }
}


Look at my code to select all the total values. I used "[id *= txtPrice]", or you can use *=Qty. I mean, I suppose you could use first or near in the query selector, but as above code shows, it is a easy and nice way to select controls from a given row by using replace. So, in my above example, I selected all txtPrice and totaled them up from that GridView. And since you using ".", then that means selecting by the class for that control, and thus what you have also should work fine to select all, but without row id's, then your selecting can mess up easy. I suggest the replace approach.

THank you, is it possible to read multiple columns using your below lines of code?
     var myGrid = $("#myGridList")  // select list view area (div)
            myTotalcols = myGrid.find("[id *= txtPrice]")   
            var myTotal = 0;
            myTotalcols.each(function () {
                myvalue = DollarToNum(this.innerText)
                myTotal += myvalue
            });
}

I need to calculate qty * token for each row and need partid while saving as below
arCartItems.push({
         "PartID": partID,
          "Qty": quantity
});


Well, if you ALWAYS do the calculation for the one row, then the table should always be correct, should it not? I mean, the table is sent + rendered from the server with the correct calulations. And my above code does the calulations for one row, so, in theory it should not be possible to have a table that is not correct, since each row is always kept correct if we run the calculations for the one row. If you need multiple columns total, we STILL don't have to re-do the calculations, since we can assume that one row is ALWAYS correct. You can most certainly have several columns to total up.

Hi Albert, Thanks for your help, I removed ClientIDMode="Static" at the Listview level and added ClientIDMode="Predictable" in few columns which I want to read in Client side.

No worries. That "trick" of using a replace is still very handy to keep in your bag of tricks.  So with a 5th row being say ListView1_Qty_4, and say ListView1_Price_4, then we can replace the Qty to "Price" and we have a valid jQuery selector for that one control in that given LV row.
